# Working with List<List<string>> in c#

Tags: c#, list, multidimensional-array

I am new to c# and I don't fully understand how lists work. Here is my scenario...

I have a `List<List<string>>` that looks like this, `{ {x, y, value} }`.

Example: `{ {1, 10, Red}, {6, 34, Black}, {2, 19, Yellow} }`

What I need to know is how to do this,

`if(x == 6 && y == 34)` then value = Black(in this example).

I have 100 items in the `List<List<string>>`. How do I search the entire thing looking at the values of the first two strings(x and y) and then retrieving the third value("value")?

Comment: Instead of a list of lists, why don't you just have a list of objects? The {1, 10, Red} doesn't really appear to be a list anyway. It looks more like an object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am new to c# and I don't fully understand how lists work.

A `List<T>` is implemented as an array under the hood. So when you write something like this:

```
var names = new List<string>() {"George", "Jerry", "Cramer", "Elaine" };
```

You just created a list with four `string` types in it. If you were to do this:

```
// it will return George because it is accessing item at index 0
var name = names[0];
```

And if you do this:

```
var anotherList = new List<List<string>>();
anotherList.Add(names);
```

You are creating a list which has another list at each index. So if you did this:

```
// It will return a list because each index has a list in it.
var item = anotherList[0];
```

In your case what you should, and it will make things a lot easier is to create a class:

```
public class XyValueClass // or a better name
{
    // Change to string if it is not integer
    public int X { get; set; }

    // Change to string if it is not integer
    public int Y { get; set; }

    public string Color { get; set; }
}
```

Then you can do this:

```
var xyValues = new List<XyValueClass>();
xyValues.Add(new XyValueClass { X = 1, Y = 10, Color = "Red" });
```

Then when you are searching, you can do this:

```
// this will return Red
var color = xyValues.Single(item => item.X == 1 && Y == 10).Color;
```

Use `Single` if you know the item is there and only one item with that condition is there. Use `SingleOrDefault` if you know there could only be one item or possibly none. Use `Where` if you think there would be 0 or more items with that condition.

Answer (score 1):

```
List<List<string>> lsts = new List<List<string>>
{
    new List<string>{"1", "10", "Red"}, 
    new List<string>{"6", "34", "Black"},
    new List<string>{"2", "19", "Yellow"} 
};

var values = lsts.Where(l => l[0] == "6" && l[1] == "34").Select(l => l[2]); // "Black"
```

Answer (score 1):

how about this? Working directly with your `List<List<string>>` structure:

```
public static void TestLists()
{
    List<List<string>> lists = new List<List<string>> { new List<string>{"1", "10", "Red"},new List<string>{"6", "34", "Black"},new List<string>{"2", "19", "Yellow"}};
    foreach (var aList in lists)
    {
        var p = new ListParser(aList);
        if (p.IsValid)
        {
            if (p.x == 6 && p.y == 34)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Found desired list: x={p.x}, y={p.y}, Value={p.value}");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Found another list: x={p.x}, y={p.y}, Value={p.value}");
            }
        }
    }
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

by using an `assisting` class `ListParser`:

```
public class ListParser
{
    public int x;
    public int y;
    public string value;
    public bool IsValid = false;
    public ListParser(List<string> row)
    {
        if (row != null && row.Count >= 3 && int.TryParse(row[0], out x) && int.TryParse(row[1], out y))
        {
            IsValid = true;
            value = row[2];
        }
    }
}
```

and here is the output:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This code smells pretty bad but it would be something like this:

```
var outerList = new List<List<string>>()
{
    new List<string>() { x="1", y="10", c=(string)Colors.Red },
    new List<string>() { ... },
    new List<string>() { ... },
    ....etc....
};

outerList.Select(inner => inner.Where(a => a.x == 6 && a.y == 34).Select(a => a.c));
```

Answer (score 0):

As another (maybe more flexible) option, define a new class:

```
public class Item
{
    public int x;
    public int y;
    public Color value;
}
```

Now you can have a list of *Item* and use Linq. For example:

```
List<Item> mylist;
var s = mylist.FirstOrDefault(a => a.x==6 && a.y == 36).value;
```